# Delphi 6 consuming C# Web service Access violation error when pass string parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi

Delphi 6 consumes c# web service when call web method with pass string as parameter, application throws Access violation error.

C# Web service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using ADODB;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RemoteReportService
/// </summary>

[WebService(Namespace = "http://sample.org/")]

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class RemoteReportService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

 [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        List<string> logtext = new List<string>();
        logtext.Add(string.Format(
            "{0}: passingQuery \"{1}\" :", DateTime.Now,
            "HelloWorld Executed"));

        string passingQuery = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, logtext);

        using (StreamWriter objwriter = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt"))
        { objwriter.Write(passingQuery); }
        return "Hello World";
    }

  [WebMethod]  //Method 2
    public string getValue(string resultString)
    {
        //string querytoExecute = null,oracleProcedure = null;

        List<string> logtext = new List<string>();


        logtext.Add(string.Format(
            "{0}: passingQuery for GetOracleValue method is \"{1}\" :", DateTime.Now,
            resultString));

        string passingQuery = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, logtext);

        using (StreamWriter objwriter = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "log.txt"))
        { objwriter.Write(passingQuery); }


        return resultString;
    }
}
```

The above web service consumed in Delphi 6

Delphi Code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button22Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sQryValue: string;
  engine: RemoteReportServiceSoap;    
begin    
  engine := GetRemoteReportServiceSoap;

  //No error when call web method (there is no parameter)
  sQryValue:= engine.HelloWorld;

  //Access violation error when call below web method
  //(passing string eventhough consider as '')
  sQryValue := engine.getValue('Test string');  // Access violation error.
end;
```

Even though I added below line added in abcd.pas file (WSDL import into abcd.pas)

```
InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(RemoteReportServiceSoap), ioDocument);
```

Still I am getting Access violation error when pass string value as parameter.

Hi,  Here I added Delphi interface file.

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : http://10.10.10.46/SampleService/RemoteReportService.asmx?wsdl
// Encoding : utf-8
// Codegen  : [wfDebug,wfVerbose,wfSkipHttpBindings,wfIgnoreSchemaErrors,wfSkipUnusedTypes]
// Version  : 1.0
// (02-11-2016 10:16:10 - $Revision:   1.9.1.0.1.0.1.9  $)
// ************************************************************************ //

unit RemoteReportService;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, Types, XSBuiltIns;

type


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://sample.org/
  // soapAction: http://sample.org/%operationName%
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // binding   : RemoteReportServiceSoap
  // service   : RemoteReportService
  // port      : RemoteReportServiceSoap
  // URL       : http://10.10.10.46/SampleService/RemoteReportService.asmx
  // ************************************************************************ //
  RemoteReportServiceSoap = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{3150DBF2-3DCE-5C59-9A7A-A4E672001C40}']
    function  HelloWorld: String; stdcall;
    function  getValue(const resultString: String): String; stdcall;
  end;

function GetRemoteReportServiceSoap(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''): RemoteReportServiceSoap;


implementation
  uses SOAPHTTPClient;

function GetRemoteReportServiceSoap(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string): RemoteReportServiceSoap;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://10.10.10.46/SampleService/RemoteReportService.asmx?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://10.10.10.46/SampleService/RemoteReportService.asmx';
  defSvc  = 'RemoteReportService';
  defPrt  = 'RemoteReportServiceSoap';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  try
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;

    Result := (RIO as RemoteReportServiceSoap);
  finally
    if Result = nil then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(RemoteReportServiceSoap), 'http://sample.org/', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(RemoteReportServiceSoap), 'http://sample.org/%operationName%');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(RemoteReportServiceSoap), ioDocument);

end.
```

Comment: Post the code for your delphi interface.

Comment: Hi I added Delphi interface file here.